When using PowerShell cmdlet Set-PSGSuiteConfig in a function it always fails with a path error
I can successfully set my PSGSuite config when is is part of my script but when I put this into a function it always fails with "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." The following code run from my main script works.


$config = (Get-Content .\googlews.json) | ConvertFrom-Json
$PSGSuite_Paramaters = @{
    ConfigName             = $config.configname.trim()
    P12KeyPath             = $config.P12KeyPath 
    AppEmail               = $config.AppEmail 
    AdminEmail             = $config.AdminEmail 
    CustomerID             = $config.CustomerID 
    Domain                 = $config.Domain  
    ServiceAccountClientID = $config.ServiceAccountClientID
}
Set-PSGSuiteConfig @PSGSuite_Paramaters



This is the JSON config file:

This is the function and the function call:


function Connect-Google
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([PSCustomObject])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$configPath
    )
    Begin
    {
        $Connected = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Status = "Failed to connect"
            Error  = ""
        }
    }
    Process
    {
        try
        {
            $loaded = Get-Module PSGSuite
            if ($null -eq $loaded)
            {
                Import-Module $global:PSGSuite
            }
            $config = (Get-Content $configPath) | ConvertFrom-Json
            $PSGSuite_Paramaters = @{
                ConfigName             = $config.configname.trim()
                P12KeyPath             = $config.P12KeyPath 
                AppEmail               = $config.AppEmail 
                AdminEmail             = $config.AdminEmail 
                CustomerID             = $config.CustomerID 
                Domain                 = $config.Domain  
                ServiceAccountClientID = $config.ServiceAccountClientID
            }
            Set-PSGSuiteConfig @PSGSuite_Paramaters
            $Connected.Status = "OK"
        }
        catch
        {
            $Connected.Error = $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Error -Message $($_.Exception.Message) 
        }
        finally 
        {
            Write-Output $Connected
        }
    }
    End
    {
    }
}

$Connect = Connect-Google -configPath .\googlews.json
if (!($Connect.Status -eq "OK"))
{
    throw $Connect.Error
}



This appears to be related to the P12KeyPath.  I have used a full path as well as just the file name being in the directory where I run the script.
I have validated that the $config values populate correctly in both the script and the function.
Why would this code being in a function fail?

Can you post the working example in your script and the failing invocation as a function? The error message seems to be pretty insistent that Set-PSGSuite-Canfig expects a Path parameter, which you’ve not supplied in your splat hashtable…

Sanity check question - are you sure it’s Set-PSGSuiteConfig that’s giving the error message? Could it be Get-Content because $configPath is somehow null? If you add a write-host “calling Set-PSGSuiteConfig immediately before the call to Set-PSGSuiteConfig do you see that line written to the consile?

Good Sanity check, but alas, the config load via get-content is fine.  I have stepped through both streams in an effort to understand.  It gets deep into the PSGSuite module before it finally kicks out and at present it is unclear to me what exactly is failing on the PSGSuite side.

If this is the PSGSuite module you're using... https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSGSuite/2.36.4/Content/PSGSuite.psm1 then there's a line in the Set-PSGSuiteConfig function that reads $configHash["$ConfigName"]['ConfigPath'] = (Join-Path $(Get-Module PSGSuite | Get-ConfigurationPath -Scope $Script:ConfigScope) "Configuration.psd1")  - my guess wouldbe that for whatever reason, that's evaluating $(Get-Module PSGSuite | Get-ConfigurationPath -Scope $Script:ConfigScope) to $null and causing the error. If you wanted to test that you could edit the....

PSGSuite.psm1 and add some write-host lines around that to see if that's at least the cause of the error...
